# Why do I consider logic to be so important?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

I note logic's nature to be contradictory. How there's no meaning in everything, so overall logic isn't considered more fundamental to the universe, but in the same arguement I rely on logic for everything and can"t seem to answer why it's important to me.

Comment: What faculty do you think you've used to determine that logic can sometimes be contradictory or that there's no meaning in everything?

Comment: It's the laws of thought. Can't get away from them. Why do you conclude that 'logic's nature' is to be contradictory? Or that there's no meaning in anything? Why would logic (thus reason and rationality) not be important to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are human, and logic is part of our intuitive heritage.  There are some aspects of behavior that are too basic to be rid of, and those things are embedded in our emotional makeup.

I agree with E.O. Wilson that the feeling of 'consilience' is a crucial instinct of our species.  These feelings, ranging from the calm assurance of finally understanding what a given word means, to the blinding 'aha' of a major scientific discovery, is the basis for all of our attachment to logic and mathematics, as well as the deductive sense necessary to establish a shared vocabulary, etc.

What has the problematic history is our ability to share that instinct with others and to record it in ways that do not mislead us.  Our cultures really require that none of us, at least not among the phenotypically normal, really disagree on the nature of logic.